# How can I retrieve an object via its reference object property in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an object `wallet` with a reference property of `Company`.

```
  const walletSchema = new Schema(
  {
    type: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'WalletType'
    },
    owner: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'Company'
    },      {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'last_updated' }
  }
);



 const companySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 50,
    required: true
  },
  staff_size: {
    type: Number,
  }
```

)

I am trying to get the Wallet with a particular company name. My this is my query below, but it seems to not work.

```
await this.find({owner: { name : { $regex: term, $options: 'i' }}})
         .populate(
           {
             path: 'type',
             select: '_id name'
           },
           {
             path: 'owner',
             select: 'name'
           }
         )
        .sort({ last_updated: -1 })
        .exec();
```

I get the error `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ name: { '$regex': 'Gambeat', '$options': 'i' } }" at path "owner" for model "Wallet"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below wouldn't work because the query is performed first before the populate. At the point of querying the model, the owner name hasn't been populated at that time.

```
await this.find({owner: { name : { $regex: term, $options: 'i' }}})
         .populate(
           {
             path: 'type',
             select: '_id name'
           },
           {
             path: 'owner',
             select: 'name'
           }
         )
        .sort({ last_updated: -1 })
        .exec();
```

What you could do is that when populating the owner, you only populate the owner with the said name. This should work:

```
let wallets = await this.find({}).populate(
               {
                 path: 'type',
                 select: '_id name'
               },
               {
                 path: 'owner',
                 match: {name: { $regex: term, $options: 'i' }},
                 select: 'name _id'
               }
             )
            .sort({ last_updated: -1 })
            .exec();
```

This still returns all the wallets but would have some company field null. so you can filter to get just the ones with company not null.

```
wallets = wallets.filter((wallet) => wallet.company)
```